# how can I make strptime work on a vector of struct tm in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, memset, strptime

I'm working in a c++ application that read a csv file and stores the content in a matrix of doubles and in a vector of struct tm. I have something similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<struct tm> tmTM;
  strptime("20020202", "%Y%m%d", &tmTM[0]);
  cout << tmTM[0].tm_year << endl;
  cout << tmTM[0].tm_mday << endl;
  cout << tmTM[0].tm_mon << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunly this code generate a error Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I'm a begginer in c++ so I don't know what is wrong with the code. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your vector is empty, yet you access its non existent first element.

Comment: I should use memset like this?  `memset(&tmTM[0], 0, sizeof(struct tm));`

Comment: No. Figure out how to use an `std::vector` (or any other library code you use. Using things without a basic understanding isn't very safe.)

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor for a `vector` generates an empty vector. That means that *any* access to an element, even element `[0]`, will result in undefined behavior.

The usual way to handle this is to work with a temporary variable, then use `push_back` to place the temporary into the vector.

```
struct tm temp;
strptime("20020202", "%Y%m%d", &temp);
tmTM.push_back(temp);
```